# Android pause specific thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following thread code that send message when it sleep. I having some trouble about pausing it. How I can do it ? I cannot see the id and I do not want to stop all thread, but only this.

```
 new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }               
                    Message m5 = d.obtainMessage();
                    d.sendMessage(m5);                  
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create one class and use it's method `onPause` and `onResume`.

```
class YourRunnable implements Runnable {
private Object mPauseLock;
private boolean mPaused;
private boolean mFinished;

public YourRunnable() {
    mPauseLock = new Object();
    mPaused = false;
    mFinished = false;
}

public void run() {
    while (!mFinished) {
        // Do stuff.

        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            while (mPaused) {
                try {
                    mPauseLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Call this on pause.
 */
public void onPause() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Call this on resume.
 */
public void onResume() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = false;
        mPauseLock.notifyAll();
    }
 }
}
```

May this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To pause a thread just call `wait()` from that `Thread`.

Then call `notify()` to resume it.